# django select_related() and django-mptt. How to fetch all the siblings at once?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-mptt, mptt

I'm trying to fetch all the siblings of the current page. The `Page` model looks like this:

```py
class Page(MPTTModel):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, blank=True) # changing to CharField from SlugField
    markdown = models.TextField()
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True,
                                 blank=True, related_name='children')
```

The code for fetch all the sublings pages looks like this:

```py
pages = page.get_siblings(include_self=True)
```

The problem is that the above code hits the database for each page. So If there are 50, it would result in 50 queries.

I have tried to solve the problem using `select_related()` but to no avail. Here is what I tried.

```py
pages = page.get_siblings(include_self=True).select_related()

# this too doesn't work
pages = page.get_siblings(include_self=True).select_related('parent')
```

While searching for solutions I stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/issues/88) page. Which shows that the `select_related()` can be called with the `get_siblings()`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the *n* queries. What does your tree look like?

Comment: The culprit was the `get_absolute_url()` method. It was getting called for each page. I resolved it by adding a column to store the url. That's it. should I close the question?

Comment: If it was resolved in a way that is unlikely to help future readers, then yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns our that django-mptt was working fine, the culprit was the `get_absolute_url()` method. I resolved the issue by adding a column to store the url.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use the standard way to access sibling/parent objects in the Django Model paradigm?

You can find an example here:

- [Django: how to query parent model based on a filter of a child model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57784766/django-how-to-query-parent-model-based-on-a-filter-of-a-child-model/57785868#57785868)
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships

In your particular case the snippet should be the following:

`MPTTModel.objects.filter(page__pk=page.pk)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But It turns our that django-mptt was working fine, the `get_absolute_url()` method was causing the issue.